# Editing and overwriting a text file with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have a text file that has 148 lines, and 4 columns visually (strings of characters separated by commas).

First, I would like to completely delete the first and the third columns. Now I'm left with two columns (separated by a comma).
Second, I would like to delete the first data entry (top left most entry in the first column, i.e. row 1 column 1) and also delete the very last data entry (bottom right most entry in the second column, i.e. row 148, column 2). Third, Now that I have only two columns I would like to swap the entries, since the first entry in the top left column is deleted, I would like the entry in the top right column to replace the deleted one, and the entry in the second row first column to replace the entry in the entry in the top right column (row 1, column 2), which has just been moved. Then I keep doing that till the end of the file. The picture attached here should help. enter image description here

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your code you have written so far and explain what exactly is your problem (where you're stuck). If you need more advice on how to ask questions efficiently so you will most likely get help I recommend to have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the file as follows:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = [l.split(',') for l in data]
```

Now you will have your data in a list of lists manner and you can edit it as you like.

Comment: So I'm assuming that splits them into four columns, but how do I see it visually so that I can delete the first and fourth column for example?

Comment: You can try this:
`data = [l[1:3] for l in data]`